# base64 Image MongoDB will not Display on Img Tag

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

I saved a based 64 image on my MongoDB, part of capturing digital signature and storing it on MongoDB.

so the data stored looks like this.

```
data: '"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABBoAAAEsCAYAAABtx9BIA...
```

When I display the raw data on an image tag it works perfectly,

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABBoAAAEsCAYAAABtx9BIA..."/>
```

But when i try to display it via ejs it does not work, example:

```
<img src=<%= data %>/>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong! Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: You probably should be showing how it renders in ejs. The immediate thing I can see from the limited detail is that `data` is surely just the name of a "key" in your document returned from MongoDB. It's unlikely that you actually referenced another variable with simply the value of this key in what you are using in the template, and you are probably just pointing at the "document" rather than the specific value. Ie if you are doing something like `res.render('page', { data: doc })` then you template should instead be using `<% data.data %>`. Can't really tell without seeing what you pass.

Comment: Yes, the data is key within a collection in my mongoDB. Collection is employee and it returns all the info correctly when I render the page....so I'm actually using `<% employe.data %>` ....it runs fine when I run the data inside a div....I see exactly...`"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABBoAAAEsCAYAAABtx9BIA...`. But not when I run it inside the img tag.

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove the quotes from the mongodb data it display it like this

```
<img src="<%= employee.data.replace(/"/g,"") %>">
```

Answer (score 0):

if your data comes like this

```
src='"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABBoAAAEsCAYAAABtx9BIA..."'
```

it wont work. probably when you pick your data it comes with the apostrophe ' '
try removing it. probably thats how ejs has outputted the data on the src tag

Answer (score 0):

split the string at the comma, the data:image/png;base64, isn't actually part of the base64